# Импорт из другого пакета Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Нужно создать два класса в разных пакетах и импортировать метод из одного класса в другой. Вопрос, как правильно создать эти два класса в `IDEA`? Я создал два проекта, в каждом класс в своём пакете, в `IDEA` и импортировать один в другой и запустить получается, но командной строкой не выходит. Потом создал один проект и в нем два класса в разных пакетах и вроде структура каталогов выглядит логичнее, но собрать каждый класс в .jar не получается. Какой из способов верен?

Comment: Не совсем понятен Ваш вопрос. Предоставьте последовательность действий (команд) и ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

В Java можно импортировать только статические методы. Привожу простой пример того, как это делается. Класс из первого пакета:

```
package package1;

public class ClassOne {

    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

Класс из второго пакета:

```
package package2;

import static package1.ClassOne.sayHello;

public class ClassTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sayHello();
    }
}
```

При выполнении метода `main` класса `ClassTwo` в консоль будет выведен результат метода `sayHello()` класса `ClassOne`.

Comment: Спасибо, это я понимаю, я импортирую сразу класс. Я не могу понять как должная выглядеть структура каталогов. Правильно ли создавать два отдельных проекта? Я создаю два отдельных проекта, делаю импорт в Idea и все работает, но когда я хочу скомпилировать из командной строки, то в -sourthpath не получается прописать путь к импортируемому файлу из другого проекта.
Расположение файлов такое: 
.../IdeaProjects/ClassOne/src/com/example/one/One.java
.../IdeaProjects/ClassTwo/src/com/example/two/Two.java

Comment: Нет, два отдельных проекта - неверный подход в решении данной задачи. Если сильно упрощать, то напрямую обращаться к функциям других классов можно только в пределах одного проекта. Вам следует создать **в одном проекте** два пакета и классы в них. Для интеграции разных проектов существуют различные способы, но их рассмотрение выходит за рамки заданного вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

> Я создал два проекта, в каждом класс в своём пакете, в idea иимпртировать один в другой и запустить получается, но командной строкой не выходит.

Чтобы при запуске класса из одного jar-файла он видел другой нужно добавить его в аргументы запуска `classpath` (или `cp`):

```
java -cp project1.jar project2_main_class
```

> Потом создал один проект и в нем два класса в разных пакетах и вроде структура каталогов выглядит логичнее, но собрать каждый класс в .jar не получается

Нет необходимости собирать классы одного проекта в отдельные jar-файлы. Собирайте весь проект в один и запускайте:

```
java -jar project.jar
```

> Какой из способов верен?

Если ваши классы используются только для реализации общей функциональности и один без другого смысла не имеют, то нужно держать их вместе (упаковывать в одну библиотеку). В противоположном случае - каждый из них включает какой-то свой функционал и они могут быть использованы в других проектах, то можно упаковывать в отдельные библиотеки и подключать при необходимости.

Comment: Я встаю в директорию ../IdeaProjects/ClassOne/ и выполняю команду:
javac -sourcepath ./src -d bin src/com/example/one/One.java

Файл, который нужно импортировать лежит ../IdeaProjects/ClassTwo/target/ClassTwo.jar

Соответственно ничего не выходит, файл не находит, пытался и полный путь к нему прописать, но также не получается.

Comment: как запускали? приведите пример строки запуска. Должно быть примерно так: `java -cp ../IdeaProjects/ClassTwo/target/ClassTwo.jar com.example.one.One` (но нужно проверить пути до ваших файлов)

Comment: Компилировал так: javac -sourcepath ./src -d bin src/com/example/one/One.java

Со вторым классом, в котором нет импортов все сработало, а вот с первым не работает.

Comment: Как запускали 1й класс и какие ошибки получили?

Comment: У меня два класса ClassOne и ClassTwo. В ClassTwo метод, который я импортирую в классе ClassOne. ClassTwo я скомпилировал командной строкой, которую привел выше, все сработало, далее собрал с помощью Maven и получил .jar файл. Тут все получилось. Далее мне нужно скомпилировать ClassOne, но из-за импорта это сделать из командной строки не получается, выдает ту же ошибку, что и при компиляции без -sourcepath, то есть он просто не нахдит jar'ку, которую нужно импортировать.

Comment: я вас все прошу привести именно строки, которые вы в командную строку вводите, на словах итак понятно. и еще, сейчас классы в одном проекте?

Comment: Так я ее несколько раз привел, ввожу: javac -sourcepath ./src -d bin src/com/example/one/One.java
Классы в разных проектах, в этом и загвоздка, если бы в дном, то проблемы не было.

Comment: это компиляция, а не запуск

Comment: java -classpath ./bin com.example.one.One

Comment: судя по строке запуска вы находитесь в директории 1го проекта и в `./bin` нет jar-файла 2го проекта

Comment: Именно. Если закинуть jar второго проекта, то работает. Главный вопрос и был в том,  как выйти из этой ситуации, будет ли правильным просто закинуть jar-файла 2го проекта или надо по-другому прописывать путь к нему? Я пытался и вставать в папку IdeaProject и из нее уже прописывать полные пути до файлов, но не получается.

Comment: Закидывать jar второго проекта к 1му может быть неудобным - вам придется это делать каждый раз при пересборке 2го проекта. Лучше в `cp` указывайте прямой путь до 2го проекта. Либо еще один вариант - если вы планируете собирать оба проекта в jar-файлы, то просто добавьте 2ой в качестве зависимости в 1й и после его сборки он будет внутри jar-файла (и затем запуск `java -jar project1.jar`).

Comment: Сейчас еще раз попробовал, работает если папку two в которой файл ClassTwo.java закинуть в папку example первого проекта. И вроде получается логично: com/example/ и в ней две папки one и two. Но с другой стороны это кажется неправильным, ведь они в первом проекте, а хочется запустить без перекидывания папки.

Comment: "перекидывание" файлов одного проекта в другой - плохая идея

Comment: А не подскажете, как прописать правильно путь без перекдывания?
Пробую встать в папку IdeaProjects и выполнить javac -sourcepath ./ClassTwo/src -d bin ClassOne/src/com/example/one/One.java

Comment: `javac -cp ./ClassTwo/target/ClassTwo.jar -sourcepath ./ClassOne/src -d bin ClassOne/src/com/example/one/One.java`

Comment: Все равно ошибки does not exist import